# Dynamic created HTML does not reload

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I'm having a kind of problem that I think is related to how I generate my HTML... I use a JavaScript function to generate some HTML, but then it begins to misfunction... let me first paste some of my code

First, my raw HTML

```
  <div id="effect">
    <label for="s_effect">Effect: </label>
    <select name="s_effect" id="s_effect" onchange="ne();"> 
      <option value="">Select your Effect</option>
    </select>
    <div id="effect_description"></div>
    <div id="effect_options"></div>
  </div>
```

Then, I have a function that loads "s_effect" based on an array (that's fine and working, np).

Then, my `ne()` (new effect) function:

```
function ne(){
  reset();
  e = g('s_effect');

  if(newEffect(e.options[e.selectedIndex].value)){
    console.log("new effect created");
    updateScreen();
  }
}
```

It basically "resets" parts of the screen (error tracking and that, stuff not related with my problem), then calls to `updateScreen()` (note: g function is just a synonym for document.getElementById)

It goes to this function (sorry it's a lot of code...)

```
function updateScreen(){
  if(project.effect instanceof Effect){
    lock("instant");
    lock("event");
    showDescription();
    generateOptions();
  }else if(project.effect == null){
    unlock("instant");
    unlock("event");
  }

  if(project.check()){
    generateButton();
  }else{
    npButton();
  }
}
```

That basically, locks some part of the window, then get some HTML on calls below.

`generateDescription()`, the part is giving trouble, does the following:

```
function generateOptions(){
  g('effect_options').innerHTML = '';
  effectID = project.effect.calculateId();

  if(effectID === false)
    return false;

  g('effect_options').innerHTML = project.effect.parameters.HTMLOptions;
  return true;
}
```

It calls to an object attribute that basically dumps some HTML code:

```
<div>
    <label for="1_color">Color: </label><input type="color" id="1_color" name="1_color" onchange="updateColor('1_color');" value="#FFFFFF">
    <input type="text" name="1_color_rgb" id="1_color_rgb" onchange="updateColor('1_color_rgb');" value="#FFFFFF">
</div>
<div id="extra"></div>
<div>
    <input type="button" value="Add Node" onclick="addNode();">
</div>
```

Finally, `addNode()` makes an `innerHTML += [new div on "extra"]` but increasing the number (2_color, 2_color_rgb, and so on).

```
function addNode(){
  var count = ++(project.effect.parameters.colorCount);
  g('extra').innerHTML +=
  '<div><label for="' + count + '_color">Color: </label><input type="color" id="' + count + '_color" name="' + count + '_color" onchange="updateColor(\'' + count + '_color\');" value="#FFFFFF" />' +
  '<input type="text" name="' + count + '_color_rgb" id="' + count + '_color_rgb" onchange="updateColor(\'' + count + '_color_rgb\');" value="#FFFFFF" /></div>' + 
}
```

To this point everything is working fine, even "updateColor" works (it updates the value of each input so you can choose a color by filling any input).

The problem comes when I modify any x_color or x_color that has been added via button... It adds a new "node" but restarts the values of previous inputs.

I debugged it, and by the point is doing the adding, the `innerHTML` of "extra" shows all inputs with "#FFFFFF" values (initial), but on the screen, the values are right...

Any help with this may be appreciated.

PS: I'm using chrome.

Thank you!

Comment: If you could put together a jsFiddle with your code, it would go a long way in helping us see the current effect and better understand the issue. FWIW - you haven't included the code for `addNode()` which, interestingly enough, is the very place you said the problem was occurring.

Comment: So your element is dynamically created? It sounds like you may need to make use of event delegation.

Comment: @Forty3 added the code. What's jsFiddle? (sorry not used to ask JS stuff here)

Comment: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) - a means to assemble an example of working (or non working) code which gives others a chance to lend a hand.

Comment: @DavidSoléGonzález can you give us the full page code

Comment: @Forty3 ah, ok. I use JSBin, looks the same. Here is the problem replicated: https://jsbin.com/vilaqimora/edit?js,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue, it appears, is that by reassinging the `.innerHTML` property of the `g('extra')` DOM element, you are telling the browser to re-render the element based on the HTML -- not the DOM elements and values contained within.

In other words, when you add a color, the `g('extra').innerHTML` gets updated with the new HTML to render an additional color selection block (i.e. `2_color`). When a user then picks a new color, the browswer will update the value for the `2_color` DOM element but doesn't necessarily update the `innerHTML` property for `g('extra')`. Then, when another color block is added, the `innerHTML` is updated once more and the browser re-renders it thereby "resetting" the values.

Instead of constructing the additional controls using HTML string, use DOM manipulation (e.g. `.createElement()` and `.append()`) in order to add your new options.

Comment: Ok I see your point. Will try asap and share my results. Thanks!

Comment: That's it. I added an answer explaining the changes I made based on your comment (just to clarify). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify, as @Forty3 answered, the problem was the fact that I was modifying the `innerHTML` each time, making my browser to re-render `extra` each time.

As he suggested, I edited my function, now looks like

```
function addNode(){
    var count = ++(project.effect.parameters.colorCount);
    var nDiv  = document.createElement("div");
    nDiv.innerHTML = "whatever I was putting...";
    g('extra').appendChild(nDiv);
}
```

Now it works fine.

Thank you all for the support.